# Word macro to set image layout and size

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to record a macro that will set the size of a pasted image to 6.5 x 4 cms and the image layout 'in front of text'. I usually set this by right clicking on the image and setting the picture properties but this isn't available when recording the macro. Using Shift-F10 does bring up the menu, but the option to set the image layout properties is greyed out.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: If you do a web search on AuthorTec Insert and another on AuthorTec Resize you can see if these Word add-ins (free) do the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's interesting about the macro recorder...

If you need to do something like this in the future it will help you to know that an object with any kind of "text wrap" formatting (that "floats") is a `Shape`. An object that behaves like a character is an `InlineShape`. And you can convert between the two using `ConvertToInlineShape` / `ConvertToShape`. For future things of this nature that should give you a starting point :-)

The following code sample uses `ConvertToShape` so that text wrap formatting can be applied. (The conversion is an extra step involved that you don't have to do in the UI - Word does it for you.)

Before this happens the code changes the size, but it could also be the other way around, changing the size on the `Shape` object.

What else is happening in the code: When a picture is pasted inline it's not selected. So this code figures out how many pictures (`InlineShapes`) are already in the document up to the selection. After the paste the code then picks up the existing number of pictures up to that point, plus one, to get the picture that was just pasted.

The code uses `CentimetersToPoints` to convert the number of centimeters wanted to the Points measurement, since that's what Word uses to size graphical objects (and lots of other things).

How did I know to use `wdWrapFront`: When `shp.WrapFormat.Type =` is typed the VBA Editor will automatically show a list of valid entries for text wrap formatting. Similarly, when `shp.` is typed a list of valid properties for a `Shape` will appear, and so on. (This is called IntelliSense and is a wonderful help!)

```
Sub PasteAndSelectPicture()
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim lNrIls As Long
    Dim rngDoc As Word.Range
    Dim rngSel As Word.Range

    Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.content
    Set rngSel = Selection.Range
    rngDoc.End = rngSel.End + 1

    lNrIls = rngDoc.InlineShapes.Count
    rngSel.Paste
    ' Debug.Print rngDoc.InlineShapes.Count, lNrIls
    Set ils = rngDoc.InlineShapes(lNrIls + 1)
    ils.width = CentimetersToPoints(6.5)
    ils.height = CentimetersToPoints(4)
    Set shp = ils.ConvertToShape
    shp.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
End SUb
```

Comment: If you do a web search on AuthorTec Insert and another on AuthorTec Resize you can see if these Word add-ins (free) do the job for you.

Comment: @RichMichaels You meant to direct this at the OP, I think? Either post it to the question or "ping" the OP using the `@`